# What are the rules for the build numbers Visual Studio generates when a project build number is x.x.* or x.x.x.*?

Tags: visual-studio, versioning

What are the rules for the build numbers Visual Studio generates when a project build number is x.x.* or x.x.x.*? I don't know where the documentation for this is and Google didn't yield what I was looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules have been documented for a long time, under the [AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> You can specify all the values or you can accept the default build number, revision number, or both by using an asterisk (`*`). For example, `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")]` indicates 2 as the major version, 3 as the minor version, 25 as the build number, and 1 as the revision number. A version number such as `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]` specifies 1 as the major version, 2 as the minor version, and accepts the default build and revision numbers. A version number such as `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")]` specifies 1 as the major version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts the default revision number. The default build number increments daily. The default revision number is random.

Comment: @Jake - well, it's simple. If you want a well defined, dependable revision number, you won't be specifying `*`, will you?

Comment: The default revision number is not random. The documentation is wrong. It's a timestamp: the number of seconds since midnight local time, modulo 2.

Comment: @Peter - true, I had a recollection that it was something like that. But it's not *documented* to be so, so a future version of the compilers could do something different without breaking the contract.